# PGO using GCC : .gcda files aren't created

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm trying to optimize my library using PGO.
As all guides suggest, I've added "-fprofile-generate" flags to both, linker and compiler (gcc). I run a typical tests scenario and I nothing is created.

Are there any additional flags that I should add to compiler/linker flags?
Is there any constrain on how the program should exit for profile files to be created? A certain status?

Are there other flags that may disable PGO flags?

Edit: I have an executable that loads several .so files. I'm currently adding the flags only the one .so. Do I have to add the flags to the executable that loads the .so ?

Comment: Did you actually run the generated execuable? There are no special flags, just running it will produce it. Otherwise, you are not passing the flag correctly (needed at both compiling *and* linking stage).

Comment: Yes. I did ran the executable.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using a simple hello-world program? I suspect you are not correctly using compiling or linking to get profiling data.

Comment: Can a the executable can be copied to a different directory after compilation, aside from the obj files that were used to create it?

Comment: Yes, location matters. You can use `-fprofile-use=path` to specify the path or directory using `-fprofile-dir`.

Comment: I compile my code on one host, and run the binary on another. The host on which I run my binary doesn't have the path in which I compiled the binary(on the first host). Can this be the problem?